# Access enum variant type

Tags: rust, types, enums

I have some code like this:

```
type MyResult = Result<u8, String>;

fn main() {
    match check(42) {
        Ok(number) => println!("OK: {}", number),
        Err(msg) => println!("Error: {}", msg),
    }

    match check(1337) {
        Ok(number) => println!("OK: {}", number),
        Err(msg) => println!("Error: {}", msg),
    }
}

fn check(number: i32) -> MyResult {
    if (0..256).contains(&number) {
        Ok(number as u8)
    } else {
        Err("Out of bounds!".to_string())
    }
}
```

Instead of specifying `u8` explicitly again in `check()`, is it possible, to get this type by accessing a magic member or method of `MyResult`?
I am basically looking for something like:

```
fn check(number: i32) -> MyResult {
    if (0..256).contains(&number) {
        Ok(number as MyResult::ok_type())
    } else {
        Err("Out of bounds!".to_string())
    }
}
```

Beware that the code above is only a minimal viable example of the problem.
I want this, because I face a lot of type repetition in a more complex code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for can be seen as a “type-level function”: given a certain input type, you want to obtain a related output type. Such “functions” can be written as traits with associated types.

```rust
trait ResultTypes {
    type Ok;
    type Error;
}
impl<T, E> ResultTypes for Result<T, E> {
    type Ok = T;
    type Error = E;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```rust
Ok(number as <MyResult as ResultTypes>::Ok)
```

This may or may not be relevant to your problem, but note that this particular usage will *not* compile if `number`’s type is a type parameter. `as` conversions only allow both sides to be concrete, or generic in ways unrelated to the conversion being done; if you want to generically convert between integers, you need to do it via traits, such as with [`num_traits::cast`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/cast/fn.cast.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can let Rust infer the type:

```rust
fn check(number: i32) -> MyResult {
    if (0..256).contains(&number) {
        Ok(number as _)
    } else {
        Err("Out of bounds!".to_string())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. While this works, is it also possible to extract the type from the `MyResult` type definition?